# Magento 2.3.2 Checkout redirecting to empty cart

Tags: checkout, magento2.3.2

we have onestepcheckout extension installed with Braintree as Payment Gateway.
Everything is working fine on sandbox mode of Braintree.
When I switch to Braintree production mode and place order using Credit card , it is redirecting to empty shopping cart. I still receive order email and order is showing up all good in admin.
While I was debugging for this issue I found when I switch Magento deploy mode to developer mode , it is working fine ,but when I switch deploy mode to production mode ,it is redirecting to empty shopping cart.

Any idea what could be the issue 
we are using Nexcess cloud as hosting

Comment: I was able to fix this issue , It seems like the success.phtml was missing on theme and there was a reference in layout xml for this file , once I put the success.phtml file in theme , it started working fine.